# java double linked list, simple linked list convert to double linked list

Tags: java

I have been ask to convert my simple linkedlist to double linked list, if anyone could give me a bit of guidance. ill appreciate thx.. when i'm inserting the elements with the insertionapres(elements), should i put the new node in the temp node???

```
public class dlink {

private static class node{

 private Object element;
 private node next;
 private node prev;

 public node(Object element){
         this.element = element;
         next = null;
         prev= null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I suggest you read what LinkedList does.  It is a doubly linked list and a good representation of what you should do in Java.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that you want to insert a node in the middle of two other nodes.

What you have to do, is create a new node, set the pointers `precedent` and `suivant` to the previous and next nodes, and update the pointers of the previous and next node, something like that:

[image: Double Linked List Node Insertion]

So, if you change your code to do it, it will be something like that:

```
// Insert a new node after position
public void insererApres(Object element){
    if(debut == null)
        insererDebut(element);
    else if (position == fin)
        insererFin(element);
    else {
        // First, create the new node
        Noeud nouveau = new Noeud(element);

        // Set the pointers
        nouveau.suivant = position.suivant;
        nouveau.precedent = position;

        // Update the previous node pointer
        nouveau.precedent.suivant = nouveau;

        // Update the next node pointer
        nouveau.suivant.precedent = nouveau;

        position = position.suivant;

        nbElement++;            
    }
}
```

You also have to change your other methods to always have `precedent` and `suivant` pointing to the previous/next node:

```
public void insererDebut(Object element){
    Noeud noeud = new Noeud(element);

    noeud.suivant = debut;

    if (noeud.suivant!=null)
        noeud.suivant.precedent = noeud;

    debut = noeud;

    if (nbElement == 0)
        fin = debut;

    position = debut;

    nbElement++;
}

public void insererFin(Object element){
    if(debut == null)
        insererDebut(element);
    else{   
        fin.suivant = new Noeud(element);

        fin.suivant.precedent = fin;

        fin = fin.suivant;

        position = fin;

        nbElement++;
    }               
}
```

Comment: @user3394847 I don't see that in the code I posted, do you mean `nouveau.precedent.suivant = nouveau;` ? In that case, this line of code update the `suivant` pointer of `nouveau.precedent` to make it point to `nouveau`. I could also have written it `position.suivant = nouveau;` in that particular case.

Comment: ok so for what i understand, fin.suivant.precedent = fin; is the same as position.precedent = fin;?

Comment: No, not in that case, because `fin.suivant` references the node you just created with `new Noeud(element)`, and `position` references something else (I'm not really sure what `position` is supposed to be, I just assumed that you are iterating over the list, and it can be everything).

Answer (score 0):

Not just your `insertionapres()` method, but in all your methods you need a temp. For example, in your `insererDebut()` function, you should set the `suivant` and `precedent` variables.

```
public void insererDebut(Object element){

     Noeud n = new Noeud(element);

     nbElement++;
     if (nbElement == 0){
         debut = n
         fin = debut;
     }else{
         debut.precedent = n;
         n.suivant = debut;
         debut = n;
     }
 }
```

I'm not sure what your `position` variable is for.

The other two methods should work similarly